# Gradle: how to extract contents of subdir in jar (but not subdir itself)?

Tags: java, gradle

How do I extract the **contents** of a directory inside a jar file with Gradle? The following code:

```
copy {
    from zipTree('somefile.jar')
    into 'somefolder'
    include 'dir'
}
```

Extracts *dir* into *somefolder* but I only want the contents of dir, not the directory itself. So basically if *dir* contains a file *file1* it should end up in *somefolder/file1* and not *somefolder/dir/file1*.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the best way, but it's a way:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

task unjar <<{
  ant.unzip(src: jar.archivePath, dest: "$buildDir/somefolder") {
    ant.cutdirsmapper(dirs: "1")
  }
}
```

Just change the src and dest arguments to your needs.